# Mysql not recognizing Field Names on Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am trying to create a Stored Procedure where the user can select on the front end how to group the data pulled from mysql. But from some reason when I am trying to execute the query, MySql returns the error:

> Query Error (exportEntries): Unknown column 'NumeroProducto' in 'field list'

I got this error by using some error handling code ($mysqli->error).

This is the code I am using to call the stored procedure in PHP:

```
$client = "CLT_6840";
$planta = $_GET['planta'];
$agrupacion = $_GET['agrupadoPor'];



$qry = "CALL exportEntradas('$cliente','$planta', $agrupacion)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($qry) or die('Prepare error (exportEntries): ' . $db->error);
$stmt->bind_param('sss',
  $cliente,
  $planta,
  $agrupacion
);

$stmt->execute() or die('Execute error (entradas_generales): ' . $db->error);
```

And this is how my MySql Stored Procedure looks like:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `prolog`@`%` PROCEDURE `bd_demo_13`.`exportEntradas`( IN cliente VARCHAR(10), IN planta VARCHAR(10), IN C_AGRUPACION VARCHAR(20))
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

SELECT 

eb.sCvePlanta AS Planta,
b.iConsecutivo AS IdBultoEntrada,
b.sCveEntradaBodega AS Entrada,
if(b.eTipoSeparacion <> "0", CONCAT(b.sCveEntradaBodega,"-", b.iConsecutivo), b.sCveEntradaBodega) AS NumeroEntrada,
DATE_FORMAT(eb.dFechaLlegadaMercancia, "%Y-%m-%d") AS FechaIngreso,
eb.sNumTalon AS NumeroGuia,
b.iConsecutivo AS idBulto,
b.iCantidadBultos AS CantidadBultos,
IF(eb.iCantidadBultosRecibidos = 1, ctb.sDescripcionSingular, ctb.sDescripcion) AS TipoBultos,
b.eTipoSeparacion AS TipoBulto,
cp.sNombreProveedor AS Proveedor,
eb.sComentariosGenerales AS Comentarios,
f.iFolio AS IdFactura,
f.sNumero AS NumeroFactura,
f.sNumeroPedido AS NumeroOrden,
pf.sCveClienteProveedorProducto AS NumeroProducto,
pf.iCantidadProducto AS CantidadProducto,
umc.sAbrUnidadMedida AS UMC,
cpp.sDescripcionProductoEspanol AS Descripcion,
"Entrada sin referencia" AS FechaCruce,
"Sin Caja" AS Caja,
b.sCveTrafico AS Referencia,
IF(b.sCveTrafico IS NOT NULL, CONCAT("En trámite. ", IF(mce.Comentario IS NULL, "", mce.Comentario)), mce.Comentario) AS ComentariosPropios,

#CASE WHEN b.sCveTrafico IS NOT NULL
#   THEN CONCAT("Listo para cruzar. ",mce.Comentario)
#   #THEN "Listo para cruzar"
#   ELSE mce.Comentario
#END AS ComentariosPropios,

mce.SOT AS SOT,
mce.motivoSOT AS MotivoSOT,
mce.tiempoExtraFechaInicio AS teFechaInicio,
mce.tiempoExtraHoraInicio AS teHoraInicio,
mce.tiempoExtraFechaFin AS teFechaFin,
mce.tiempoExtraHoraFin AS teHoraFin,
mce.tiempoExtraMotivo AS teMotivo,
mce.tiempoExtraDiaFestivo AS teDiaFestivo,
mce.tiempoExtraImporte AS teImporte,
mr.pkIdRetrabajo AS Retrabajos

FROM cb_bulto b

LEFT JOIN cb_entrada_bodega             eb ON b.sCveEntradaBodega = eb.sCveEntradaBodega
LEFT JOIN ct_bulto              ctb ON eb.sCveBulto = ctb.sCveBulto
LEFT JOIN cu_cliente_proveedor          cp ON eb.sCveProveedor = cp.sCveProveedor AND eb.sCveCliente = cp.sCveCliente
LEFT JOIN cb_relacion_remesa_banco_facturas     rrbf ON b.iConsecutivo = rrbf.iConsecutivoBulto
LEFT JOIN cb_factura                f ON rrbf.iFolio = f.iFolio
LEFT JOIN cb_producto_factura           pf ON f.iFolio = pf.iFolio AND f.sCveCliente = pf.sCveCliente AND f.sCveProveedor = pf.sCveProveedor 
LEFT JOIN ct_unidad_medida_comercializacion     umc ON pf.sCveUMC = umc.sCveUMC
LEFT JOIN cu_cliente_proveedor_producto     cpp ON pf.sCveClienteProveedorProducto = cpp.sCveClienteProveedorProducto AND pf.sCveCliente = cpp.sCveCliente AND pf.sCveProveedor = cpp.sCveProveedor
LEFT JOIN mahle.comentariosentradas         mce ON eb.sCveEntradaBodega = mce.fkIdEntrada AND b.iConsecutivo = mce.fkIdBulto
LEFT JOIN cb_trafico                t ON b.sCveTrafico = t.sCveTrafico
LEFT JOIN cb_detalle_orden_carga        doc ON t.sCveTrafico = doc.sCveTrafico AND b.iConsecutivo = doc.iConsecutivoBulto
LEFT JOIN cb_orden_carga            oc ON doc.iConsecutivoOrdenCarga = oc.iConsecutivo
LEFT JOIN cb_remesa_consolidada_factura     rcf ON f.iFolio = rcf.iFolioFactura
LEFT JOIN mahle.retrabajos          mr  ON mr.fkIdEntrada = eb.sCveEntradaBodega AND mr.fkIdBulto = b.iConsecutivo

WHERE eb.sCveCliente = cliente
AND (b.sCveTrafico IS NULL OR (b.sCveTrafico IS NOT NULL AND oc.iConsecutivo IS NULL))
AND eb.dFechaLlegadaMercancia <= NOW()
AND eb.dFechaLlegadaMercancia >= "2017-01-01"
AND (
    (eb.sCvePlanta = planta AND eb.sCveCliente = "CLT_6840") OR
    ((eb.sCvePlanta IS NULL OR eb.sCvePlanta IS NOT NULL) AND eb.sCveCliente <> "CLT_6840")
)

GROUP BY C_AGRUPACION;

END
```

The value contained in `$_GET['agrupadoPor']` is `NumeroProducto` and I have also tried using the actual value of the field: `pf.sCveClienteProveedorProducto`

As you can see the field name actually do exist. Any idea why this may be happening .. and furthermore .. how I can correct it?

Comment: what is the procedure definition header? the name of 3th parameter variable?

Comment: @IvanCachicatari I just updated the code with the header.. thanks!

Comment: You cannot group by a variable column name. If you want to do this, you have to use [dynamic sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). So put your whole code in a string variable and add the parameters where needed (that includes e.g. `cliente` too) with e.g. `concat`. Or put your whole code into php and construct your query there (again, as a string, but there it is more natural). Also, the correct use of `group by` would be to include every column in `select` that is not an aggregate. Otherwise you a) get random values and b) it won't work in 5.7+

Comment: Thank you @Solarflare .. I changed the code entire query to PHP instead of using stored procedure..